# Self-hosted Azure Devops build cant resolve packages

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, azure-devops

I have a Azure DevOps build pipeline that runs as expected on a hosted vs2017 agent, but fails on a self-hosted agent.

The error I get in the Visual Studio build step is:

```
C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\.NETStandard,Version=v2.0.AssemblyAttributes.cs(4,20): Error CS0400: The type or namespace name 'System' could not be found in the global namespace (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

The two agents seems to run the same version of msbuild.

From the diagnostic output from msbuild I can see that the output from the ResolvePackageDependencies task contains a lot of packages where the ResolvedPath is empty, for instance:

```
runtime.native.System/4.3.0
              Name=runtime.native.System
              Path=runtime.native.system/4.3.0
              ResolvedPath=
              Type=package
              Version=4.3.0
```

But the NuGet restore step seems to complete without problems.

Any suggestions for what I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

I believe I had a similar issue. I ended up having to install the latest Nuget and then run Nuget on the solution including a NuGet.config file.

1. Add a nuget.config to your solution so it is part of your repo/pull. Mine is in the same directory as the solution file.  Example below
2. Add a task "NuGet Tool Installer" - I install NuGet 4.4.1, just put 4.4.1 in the Version to install input.
3. Add a task "NuGet Installer" - Different from above. Version 0.* - I have not tried the other versions.

   1. Set the Path to the solution. IE. $(Build.Repository.LocalPath)/Source/Sample.sln
   2. Add the path to the Nuget config file. Example $(Build.Repository.LocalPath)/Source/nuget.config

Nuget.config contains how to get the packages.  Add other locations if you get packages from other sources like a local folder or something.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
<!--
    Used to specify the default Sources for list, install and update.
    See: nuget.exe help list
    See: nuget.exe help install
    See: nuget.exe help update
-->
<packageSources>
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
</packageSources>
<packageRestore>
  <!-- Allow NuGet to download missing packages -->
  <add key="enabled" value="True" />

  <!-- Automatically check for missing packages during build in Visual Studio -->
  <add key="automatic" value="True" />
</packageRestore>
```

Your build task should run fine now and find all the packages.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But I already have the nuget installer task in my build and it completes without problems. I can see that the packages have been downloaded, but somehow they are not used in the step that builds the solution.

Answer (score 0):

> Self-hosted Azure Devops build cant resolve packages

According to the error message, it seem nuget not restore the reference from SDK.

To resolve this issue, we need update our `nuget.exe` version to 4.0 and above.

In the NuGet tool installer we could specify the nuget.exe version:

[image]

As you comment above, it seems you have already use nuget installer, in this case, you can try to **update Visual Studio to 15.3 and above on the build server**. Because VS only adds proper support for .NET Core 2.0 SDK in version `15.3`.

Finally, if your project/solution is .net core/standard you can use `dotnet restore` and then run `dotnet build` to compile your app.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @jbiversen, Sorry that not help you. How about build the project/solution on the build server with Visual Studio directly without Azure Devops?